# "Bundle exec napa server" throws "can't get Master/Slave device (RuntimeError)" in production

Tags: ruby, ruby-grape, pty, napa

I developed my first app with [Napa](https://github.com/bellycard/napa) and now I'm trying to deploy it on my production server.
I probably did something wrong because `napa server` (or `bundle exec napa server`) throws an error and I have no idea to what to look for to solve it...

Here my stack trace

```
releases/current]# napa server
Napa server starting...
/home/partners/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3@my_awesome_app/gems/napa-0.5.0/lib/napa/cli/base/server.rb:14:in spawn: can't get Master/Slave device (RuntimeError)
from /home/partners/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3@my_awesome_app/gems/napa-0.5.0/lib/napa/cli/base/server.rb:14:in `server'
  from /home/partners/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3@my_awesome_app/gems/thor-0.19.1/lib/thor/command.rb:27:in `run'
from /home/partners/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3@my_awesome_app/gems/thor-0.19.1/lib/thor/invocation.rb:126:in `invoke_command'
from /home/partners/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3@my_awesome_app/gems/thor-0.19.1/lib/thor.rb:359:in `dispatch'
from /home/partners/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3@my_awesome_app/gems/thor-0.19.1/lib/thor/base.rb:440:in `start'
from /home/partners/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3@my_awesome_app/gems/napa-0.5.0/bin/napa:5:in `<top (required)>'
from /home/partners/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3@my_awesome_app/bin/napa:23:in `load'
from /home/partners/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3@my_awesome_app/bin/napa:23:in main
```

Indeed, this works! `bundle exec rackup config.ru`

Why? It seems I have some issues with PTY. Maybe is a matter of permissions?

Comment: This could be an issue with Napa, or your implementation of the gem.  I don't believe we have enough information to resolve this with the information you've given us.

Comment: @Kelseydh You are right too. That's the point! Is my first time with Napa and I don't have yet a clear idea of where to look for better info. The log has only that info. Server logs are empty. I tried to replicate it on another server but it works. I supposed is something related to PTY because is the only thing I don't have under my direct control, but any suggestion to check anything is welcome!